# mongodb remotely accessible though bindIp : 127.0.0.1

Tags: mongodb

I have assigned **bind IP** : **127.0.0.1** in my configuration file. still able to access my db remotely...what to do to make it secure and not accessible to others remotely

Answer (score 1):

after googling i came to know that db was not reading the config file so i made it to read the config file using --config option